# How to disable a virtual keyboard when a physical one is present?

Tags: android, android-source

I'm working with android 11 version of AOSP on STB. I want to change AOSP so that when a hard keyboard is connected to my STB device a virtual keyboard doesn't show up on the screen and vice versa. That is implemented in the phone settings of android but not the TV settings.

I've tried following what happens in phone settings when you disable the virt. keyboard and set the setShowImeWithHardKeyboard() function to always put false for SHOW_IME_WITH_HARD_KEYBOARD, but that didn't work. I've also tried modifying the showSoftInput() method inside InputMethodManager class so that it first checks if a hard keyboard exists and if it does to return false and if it doesn't to continue executign, but that also didn't really work. Browsing the android documentation didn't help all that much either. I'm new with working with AOSP so any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.